# What's the benefit of including common files in one single header file?

Tags: c++, c, include, precompiled-headers

I was looking at the doom3 code on github and I notice something unusual. Several files have only one include for a file called idlib/precompiled.h and this file have includes for several other headers like

```
...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
...
```

and to program headers

```
#include "../framework/BuildVersion.h"
#include "../framework/BuildDefines.h"
#include "../framework/Licensee.h"
#include "../framework/CmdSystem.h"
#include "../framework/CVarSystem.h"
```

I wonder if there's any good reason for that, because that's the first time I see such thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called precompiled headers. The main benefit is dramatically increased compilation speed.

All the headers in `precompiled.h` are compiled only once per project. Without precompiled headers, each header content would be compiled multiple times: for each .cpp file it is included in.

Comment: so if I put a header that is used in most part of the system and change it, it would still require almost full rebuild or only the precompiled header would need recompilation?

Comment: The precompiled header needs recomplilation. In general this means a full rebuild, since the precompiled header file is included everywhere.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't support precompilation this will massively increase compilation -time-. Whether it decreases or increases compilation speed if it does depends entirely on whether or not you ever adjust a header file. If you do, everything will have to be recompiled, which I doubt will improve compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies are best served with an include-once in the using source (pragma, guarding defines). That involves a very small overhead as you get a tree of repeated includes: including a header while including a header.

However for the standard libraries are/were sometimes not so well organized and to provide a standard base of headers this was easiest. It also reflects a kind of "module" idea, bundled headers for the basic layer.

As to local includes: it is likely to be non-object-oriented lazyiness, not expressing dependencies.